# Get a New Directory Name from Mkdir

Tags: matlab, directory, runtime

I'm running a code in Maltab the creates directories through `mkdir`. Problem is, I'm creating their name by some logic on run-time, so I don't know what the dir name would be. I know I can first create the name as

```
string dirName = nameLogic();
mkdir(dirName);
```

but I would like to know the dirName from the created directory itself. Naivly, that would be

```
[outputdirName] = mkdir(fuzzylogicdirName);
```

I should add that I'm not religiously attached to `mkdir`, and another yet more suitable method might be in place.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I might get you wrong. In any case what `mkdir` does is just creating a folder, hence the folder name must be known (possibly determined at run-time) before the call.

A structure like

```
  folderName = folderNameLogic([run_time_variables]);
  % # folderName = 'something_run_time_variables(1)_and_run_time_variables(2)'
  status = mkdir(folderName)
  if status == 1
       disp(['success in creating folder ' folderName]);
  else
       disp(['ERROR in creating folder ' folderName]);
  end
```

is thus necessary.

Clearly nothing prevents you from wrapping the call a function of yours returning the folder name. E.g.

```
 function [folderName] = mkdir_retname(folderName)
      status = mkdir(folderName);
      if status == 0
           folderName = '0';
      end
 end
```

Comment: You're right, and I've edited my question accordingly. Does any other Matlab method do the trick?

Comment: @CuriousMe, again you have to solve the fuzzy logic name definition before the call. the matlab function `mkdir` or any other won't solve the fuzzy logic for you.